# I want to change key value getting bt json from Server in iOS

Tags: ios, json, key, nsdictionary

[server]

```
array_push($msg,array("finished"=>@"1",
.
.
.) 

array_push($msgs,$msg); 

$response = array("msgs"=>$msgs);

echo json_encode($response);
```

[Client ]

```
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonParseError];

NSMutableArray * UMsgsInfoArray = [responseDict mutableArrayValueForKey:@"msgs"];

}
```

[image]

---

I want to change client's "finished" key **value(="1")** in client. 
what should I do?

---

Answer (score 0):

I am little bit confuse , if you want how to change "finished" key values then please use below -

```
[[[UMsgsInfoArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"finished"]];
```